# Using SortedDictionary for .net (imported from C# .dll)

Tags: python, .net, dictionary, python.net

I'm currently working on a python (for .NET) project that interacts with a C# .dll. However, something is wrong with the SortedDictionary I'm importing.

This is what I'm doing:

```
import clr
from System.Collections.Generic import SortedDictionary
sorted_dict = SortedDictionary<int, bool>(1, True)
```

I get the following error when calling Count on sorted_dict:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Count'
```

sorted_dict doesn't allow me to call any of the public member functions I see in the interface (Add, Clear, ContainsKey, etc.). Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: What flavor of Python interpreter are you using? I ask because if `SortedDictionary` is the name of a class, `SortedDictionary<int, bool>(1, True)` results in the tuple `(True, True)`. This would also explain the `AttributeError` you're getting. The statement is _not_ valid Python syntax.

Comment: @martineau the interpreter is CPython. The project I'm working on uses SortedDictionary<int, Object>, but I replaced Object with a bool for this question since it still doesn't work in that case. I assumed this was correct Python syntax because I didn't get any error messages regarding that, but I think that should solve this case. Thanks!

Comment: @martineau do you mind explaining why SortedDictionary<int, bool>(1, True) would return the tuple (True, True)?

Comment: This is IronPython.

Comment: In that case it's definitely a syntax issue. You're using C# syntax which the Python interpreter no comprende. I think you want something like `SortedDictionary[int, bool]` based on some coding examples I just found.

Comment: @kindall this is Python for .Net (I'm avoiding IronPython since it uses a different interpreter)

Comment: @martineau thanks a lot!

Comment: `SortedDictionary<int, bool>(1, True)` is interpreted as two valid boolean expressions, `SortedDictionary < int` and `bool > (1, True)` separated by a comma, which causes a tuple of the two results to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
SortedDictionary<int, bool>(1, True)
```

The `<` and `>` symbols in this line are being taken as *comparison operators.* Python sees you asking for two things:

```
 SortedDictionary < int
 bool > (1, True)
```

The comma between these expressions makes the results into a tuple, so you get `(True, True)` as a result. (Python 2.x lets you compare anything; the result may not have any reasonable meaning, as is the case here.)

Clearly, Python does not use the same `<...>` syntax as C# for generic types. Instead, you use `[...]`:

```
sorted_dict = SortedDictionary[int, bool](1, True)
```

This still doesn't work: you get:

```
TypeError: expected IDictionary[int, bool], got int
```

This is because you are trying to instantiate the class with two parameters, when it wants a single parameter that has a dictionary interface. So this will work:

```
sorted_dict = SortedDictionary[int, bool]({1: True})
```

Edit: I originally assumed you were using IronPython. Looks like Python for .NET uses a similar approach, so I believe the above should still work.

Answer (score 1):

"In that case it's definitely a syntax issue. You're using C# syntax which the Python interpreter no comprende. I think you want something like SortedDictionary[int, bool] based on some coding examples I just found" @martineau